# Get informations about the "calling" view using INavigationAware OnNavigatedTo method

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I'd like to know how to get the name of the View that requested the Navigate inside the OnNavigatedTo method of the called View. The Uri property of the NavigationContext gives me the Uri of the called View not of the Source view.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.navigated(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm using RegionManager.RequestNavigate(source, Uri) that rises the OnNavigatedTo method. The link you provided is about another way of navigating through views.

Answer (score 0):

You can find helpful information related to your question in the following **MSDN Prism Guide** chapter:

- [Passing Parameters During Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec10)

As the guide mentions, you would be able to pass a parameter list through the **Uri** property, which each parameter would be stored as a ***keyName - value*** pair in the **Parameters** property of the **NavigationContext** instance. In order to do this, add to the Uri, a **NavigationParameters** instance where the *keyName-value* pairs were added.

Therefore, after adding the ***SourceView*** name into the Uri, you may access it with the *Registered keyName*:

```
string sourceViewName = navigationContext.Parameters["SourceView"];
```

I hope this helped you, Regards.